# What is "depth grammar"?

Tags: grammar

I remember learning about it (ha) in linguistics class at uni, but then I went to the pub.

I remember the idea was interesting. It had something to do with the undiscovered rules of language that we must know intuitively and/or subconsciously in order to learn language in the first place.

Comment: You were thinking of [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2104496)?

Comment: @J.M. - Unfortunately I only get the abstract from that link...and it is a little dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about [deep structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_structure)?